# nginx autoindex ONLY subfolders in the mainfolder

Tags: nginx

my folder structure:

```
folder_main_x/
- folder_a
- folder_b
- folder_c
- ...

folder_main_y/
- folder_d
- folder_e
- folder_f
- ...

folder_main_z/
- folder_g
- folder_h
- folder_i
   - ...

 folder_main_.../
  -...
```

And they should reachable under this domain:

www.sync_backup_something.com/media/

The folder folder_main_xyz... should be 403 (or better a custom error message), but everything else further those folders should be reachable.

At the moment I trying to figure this with some regex out, but no success so far.

https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/nginx-location-directive/

edit:

This here works just for one specific folder:

```
location /test_media {

    root /var/www/html/;

    autoindex off;
    }

location /test_media/test_other {

    root /var/www/html/;

    autoindex on;
    }
```

But that test_other should be some regex so I can access all folders behind test_media...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After hours of testing and reading countless tuts on regex:

```
    location /test_media {

        root /var/www/html/;

        autoindex off;
        }

    location ~ /test_media/test_other/(.+)  {

        root /var/www/html/;

        autoindex on;
        }
```

I still do not know why it works or how it works, but well....it works.